# Read data in two files, one containing columns and display data if they correspond

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to compare the data in two files, one which has columns and then wish to print the data that is found in both

File 1:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

File2:

```
itemA item1
itemB item2
itemC item3
```

Hence i would like to compare File 1 with column 2 of File 2, if they are identical I would like to display the entire line.

For example if **file1** contains:

```
data1
data2
```

and **file2** contains:

```
dataA data1
dataC data3
```

would only display:

```
dataA data1
```

as this is the line in file2 with the data item in file1

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -Fwf file1 file2
```

from [`man grep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

```
-F, --fixed-strings
    Interpret PATTERN as a list  of  fixed  strings  (instead  of  regular  expressions),  separated  by
    newlines, any of which is to be matched.

-f FILE, --file=FILE
    Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined  with
    the -e (--regexp) option, search for all patterns given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and
    therefore matches nothing.

-w, --word-regexp
    Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test  is  that  the  matching
    substring  must  either  be  at  the  beginning  of  the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent
    character.  Similarly, it must be either  at  the  end  of  the  line  or  followed  by  a  non-word
    constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]++} ($2 in seen)' file1 file2
```

At above, first we are reading the *file1* and holds the entire column1 from into an array named *seen*, then look in file2 on its second column and if it's matched with the saved column1 from file1 then goes to print entire row of file2.

You also have `join` command if both files are sorted (if not, you can pass sorted output by `sort`ing):

```
join -1 1 -2 2 file1 file2
```

from [`man join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html)

```
-1 FIELD
      join on this FIELD of file 1

-2 FIELD
      join on this FIELD of file 2
```

if files are not sorted:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: Hi AFSHIN i am currently trying the awk command is it meant to print out data to the command line?

Comment: Cheers that worked, and will do :)

Comment: The `grep` command can give you false positive matches since you haven't constrained it to match at the end.

Comment: @RakeshSharma correct, but we are assuming file1 data **only and only** will present in column2 of file2.